# Symfony: Route not found in new controller

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have a misterious case of `No route found` in my application. I use annotations in my controllers. My `app/config/routing.yml` looks like this:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

All routes work perfectly fine, but now I created a new controller and it doesn't find its routes.

```
<?php
  namespace AppBundle\Controller;

  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

  /**
   * Export controller.
   * @Route("/export")
   */
  class ExportController extends Controller{
    /*
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function showExportPage(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('AppBundle:export.html.twig');
    }
  }
?>
```

If I visit the url it says `No route found for "GET /export"`. Also if I do `router:debug` in the console, the route doesn't get listed. I have cleared the cache several times, it doesn't help.

Probably I just forgot a stupid little detail, but I am really stuck right now, so any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of your php file that contains this controller ?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Are you using any locale in url ? maybe you should access /{locale}/export

Comment: The files name is "ExportController.php".
As stated, I have cleared the cache.
No, I'm not using locale anywhere.

thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: `showExportPage` should be `showExportPageAction`, but it not the reason of error.

Comment: I havent noticed any effect of the method name on anything so far...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You lack one more asterisk in an annotation block.
Like this, it is not parsed by FrameworkExtraBundle

So you need

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
```

instead of

```
/*
 * @Route("/")
 */
```

Comment: Oh my god, I knew it must be a stupid detail. Thanks a lot!